# ORA-00906 missing left parenthesis error while creating table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Getting ORA-00906 error while creating table.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.BSTXTEST(
  PDBC_PFX        CHAR      NOT NULL,
  BSBS_TYPE       CHAR      NOT NULL,
  BSTX_SEQ_NO     NUMBER    NOT NULL,
  BSTX_TEXT       RAW       NOT NULL,
  BSTX_LOCK_TOKEN NUMBER    NOT NULL,
  ATXR_SOURCE_ID  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  BSTXTEXT        VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
  LENTEXT         NUMBER    NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Size needs to be specified for the `RAW` data type as you did for `VARCHAR2`

Answer (score 0):

For a RAW datatype the size portion of the definition is mandatory.
e.g.

```
BSTX_TEXT       RAW(2000)   NOT NULL,
```